# How to create jQuery plugin to cache jQuery object as shown below

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

Problem is, in case of `e` is of type `HtmlElement`

This causes performance issue `$(e) !== $(e)` as instead of reusing jQuery object, jQuery creates new object each time when we call `$(e)`

```
$(e).attr(....
$(e).css(...
$(e).find(....
```

For each statement, new jQuery object is created and performance increases when we do

```
var $e = $(e);
$e.attr(....
$e.css(...
$e.find(....
```

so I decided to cache by rewriting $ as below. instead of changing huge code.

```
var $old = window.$;

var $ = function(o){
    if(typeof HTMLElement === "object" ? o instanceof HTMLElement : o 
        && typeof o === "object" 
        && o !== null 
        && o.nodeType === 1 
        && typeof o.nodeName==="string"){
        o.__$ = o.__$ || $old(o);
        return o.__$;
    }
    return $old(o);
};

$.prototype = $old.prototype;
```

After this `$(e) === $(e)` returns true, and in the context of page, if called multiple times, it runs pretty fast.

However, `$.trim, $.isArray` all function are gone, I have large code base that depends upon jQuery, but I want to improve speed of jQuery by caching.

Comment: What is the specific issue you have with jQuery that you are trying to overcome? I'm failing to see what gain you are after?

Comment: Actually after a re-read I think I know what you're after. You can achieve a better comparison via the  $(e).is(otherElem); method. (Negate as needed)

Comment: Ah I see. In your first code sample where the selector is re-run several times for multiple methods... That's the issue. This is bad programming practice. 2 options, like in normal code, get the result you need once and save it to a variable that you will then reference for all future method calls, or take advantage of jQuery's chaining and call $(e).doFoo().doBar().doBaz(); all chained to the original selector.

Answer (score 0):

While I now see what you are trying to achieve, I don't think modifying jQuery here is the solution.

In your example code

```
$(e).attr(...);
$(e).css(...);
$(e).find(...);
```

This does cause jQuery to re-evaluate the selector 3 times, and yes, that is going to be slower than if it was cached.  However I'd argue that modifying jQuery to do the caching is the wrong solution.

Normally in programming we "cache" the result of a fetch to a variable then make our modification on it (rather than re-fetch)

```
var e = $(e);
e.attr(...);
e.css(...);
e.find(...);
```

or with jQuery's chaining, you can do it all in one line

```
$(e).attr(...).css(...).find(...); //(wrap if desired)
```

I think that changing the behavior of jQuery to auto-cache actually promotes a bad practice of not thinking/caring about the performance of the code written.

e.g. If there was a "cool JS library" that did SQL...

```
$SQL("SELECT * FROM TABLE foo WHERE name='blah'").updateTimestamp();
$SQL("SELECT * FROM TABLE foo WHERE name='blah'").set('type','raincoat');
$SQL("SELECT * FROM TABLE foo WHERE name='blah'").set('price',57.50);
```

It would be obvious that the performance of this would suck due to constantly re-selecting the results.  I think with jQuery developers just need to remember that the selector is running a query (sometimes very fast!) but still a query thus it shouldn't be abused by calling it multiple times if not needed.

(PS I'm joking suggesting that a client side SQL query library is a good thing, ditto with SELECT *... this was just an example)

Comment: Well I understand, but what about such usage in third party library where I can't replace coding style, in my framework I have already used chaining, but I still have code that I haven't written.

Comment: If the other code is written by developers on your team/within your company I would advise them to ensure they are not writing inefficient code.  If part of an open source project on github etc. I would contribute back patches to clean up the code.  If code totally beyond your control, if there is a performance impact I would report it so that "they" (whomever they is) can fix it... and if this is the case and you know why the performance isn't good, I would provide info on what can/should be changed to improve the 3rd party code.